# Eclipse plugin command line arguments

Tags: c#, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, command-line-arguments

I have a plugin in eclipse which allow the user to create a specific type of project.
This option is enabled under File->New->Project... and it opens a wizard with some option to choose there.
I would like to open that wizard from a command line.
I am using a C# application and would like to succeed invoke:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(eclipseLocation+"Eclipse.exe", "?");
```

For now, without the second parameter it opens the eclipse.
I would like it to open the wizard of a new project also.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Eclipse command line option that would do this.

You could write an Eclipse plug-in using the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications` extension point to define a 'headless' application which would do the new project creation. You could then run this using the `-application` command line parameter.

Comment: Do you know if there a way to call a plugin button from command line? this can also help me. I don't want to implement the whole project creation, but only to open the wizard from command line. thanks.